# removing white spaces for key and value before adding to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code:

```
d = {}
for line in output.split("\n"):
    if ":" not in line:
       continue
    print line
    key, value = line.strip().split("=", 1) # Remove white spaces for value and key
    d[key] = value
```

Output has:

```
    apples : 10
    unknown : 20
```

In above code how do we do striping for key and value before adding dictionary d

Comment: Well, you answered your own question: just `.strip()` them before adding. `d[key.strip()]=...` (And you do not need the other `.strip()`.)

Comment: d[key.strip()]= value is that right?

Comment: Didn't you want to strip the value, too?

Comment: Yes needed  d[key.strip()] = value.strip()